# How to get torch::Tensor shape

Tags: c++, pytorch, libtorch

If we `<<` a `torch::Tensor`

```
#include <torch/script.h>
int main()
{
    torch::Tensor input_torch = torch::zeros({2, 3, 4});
    std::cout << input_torch << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

we see

```
(1,.,.) = 
  0  0  0  0
  0  0  0  0
  0  0  0  0

(2,.,.) = 
  0  0  0  0
  0  0  0  0
  0  0  0  0
[ CPUFloatType{2,3,4} ]
```

How to get the tensor shape (that `2,3,4`)? I searched https://pytorch.org/cppdocs/api/classat_1_1_tensor.html?highlight=tensor for an API call but couldn't find one. And I searched for the `operator<<` overload code, and also couldn't find it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `torch::sizes()` method

```cpp
IntArrayRef sizes()
```

It's equivalent of shape in python. Furthermore you can access specific size at given ax (dimension) by invoking `torch::size(dim)`. Both functions are in the API page you linked

Comment: shall be used as: ``my_tensor.sizes()`` [commenting this because I tried with ``torch::sizes(my_tensor)`` and ... it failed]

Answer (score 8):

What works for me is:

```cpp
#include <torch/script.h>
int main()
{
    torch::Tensor input_torch = torch::zeros({2, 3, 4});

    std::cout << "dim 0: " << input_torch.sizes()[0] << std::endl;
    std::cout << "dim 1: " << input_torch.sizes()[1] << std::endl;
    std::cout << "dim 2: " << input_torch.sizes()[2] << std::endl;

    assert(input_torch.sizes()[0]==2);
    assert(input_torch.sizes()[1]==3);
    assert(input_torch.sizes()[2]==4);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Platform:

```sh
libtorch 1.11.0
CUDA 11.3
```

Answer (score 0):

Well i have been using `torch::_shape_as_tensor(tensor)` which gives you another tensor object